# Search and list .m2 (local) maven repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

For a project, I want to search the local maven repo (.m2) and list the artifacts. How I can do it in Java? I found https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer and checked whether I can use it to list my local maven repo. But still couldn't solve. If you have any idea of a simple library which I can use, please suggest?

Thanks in advance. !

Comment: Does the assignment expect you to write code?  You won't learn much from using a library.  If you just need to see dependencies you can ask IntelliJ to create a graph of them for your project.

Comment: For what purpose do you need the list of artifacts in the local repository? What is the original problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the use of `Files.walkFileTree(Path start, FileVisitor<? super Path> visitor)`

```
class MyM2Visitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private final Path root;
    public MyM2Visitor(Path root) {
        this.root = root;
    }
    //implement rest as necessary
}

//later...

//Current user's .m2 directory:
Path m2 = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".m2");

MyM2Visitor visitor = new MyM2Visitor(m2);
try {
    Files.walkFileTree(m2, visitor);
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See also: [SimpleFilevisitor JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html)

You should customise the visitor to take appropriate action when encountering a directory or a file, e.g.:

```
@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    logger.trace("File: {}", file);
    int count = file.getNameCount();
    Path versionPath = file.getParent();
    String versionAsString = versionPath.getFileName();
    //or:
    versionAsString = file.getName(count-2).toString();
    String artifactId = file.getName(count-3).toString();

    Path groupIdPath = file.getParent().getParent().getParent();
    Path relativeToM2 = root.relativize(groupIdPath);
    String groupId = relativeToM2.toString().replace(File.separatorChar, '.');

    //do other things

    return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
}
```